# port specific wcf error

Tags: wcf, exception, port

we have a simple WCF NetTCPbinding file transfer utility with certificate transport security, there is a client side service that monitors folders and pushes files out from our clients.  and a server side service that listens and receives the files on our receiving server, both of these WCF services are hosted as windows services.

The service currently works perfectly on port 444, we must change this to port 443.  in our test environment everything works properly on 443 as well.  however, when attempting to switch one of our clients to port 443, we see the following error:

> The server rejected the upgrade request.
>   Error while reading message framing format at position 0 of stream (state: >ReadingUpgradeRecord)
>   Server stack trace: 
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.ValidateUpgradeResponse(Byte[] >buffer, Int32 count, ClientFramingDecoder decoder)...

when wcf tracing is turned on on the server, we see this additional exception as well:

> Expected record type 'Version', found '22'.

All information i have found on these errors seems to pertain to object types, enums ect..., which is not making any sense to me, as the service runs properly simply by switching the port.  unfortunately that is not a solution as we must use port 443.

other thoughts:
 port 443 is available and no other processes are listening on it.
 IIS is turned off.

please let me know if you have any thoughts, or need any additional information. thank you very much for your time.